# AJAX Error Handling from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My current script only handles errors with a vague & general error message when the execution fails but I'd like to have it return various error messages. Many of the other answers I find are similar to what I already have where I'm unable to do what I desire here.

**Current AJAX (What I require changed)**:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: './ajax.php',
    data: {value1: 'test', value2: 'test', isChecked: isChecked},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: this.exeSuccess,
    error: this.exeError
});


this.exeSuccess = function(){
    var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    // Highlights table row to denote successful execution
    currentRow.toggleClass('colorcode');
};

this.exeError = function(){
    alert("Error. Please try again.");
    return false;
};
```

**Current PHP:**

```
if (isset($_GET['value1']) && isset($_GET['value2']) && isset($_GET['isChecked'])) {

    // Execution logic here... if it fails, the whole script terminates
    echo json_encode("");
}
```

**What I plan on doing with PHP to return detailed error messages to AJAX:**

```
if (isset($_GET['value1']) && isset($_GET['value1']) && isset($_GET['isChecked'])) {

    $errorMessage = "";

    if (isset($_GET['isChecked']) == 'false'){
        $errorMessage = "The check box is false";
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "The check box is true";
    }

    echo json_encode("$errorMessage");  // But how I handle it in the AJAX error:?
}
```

How could I get the error messages handled in "AJAX error:" so that different **alert([error_message]**) can be executed?

Comment: The `Ajax Error:` thing happens if there is an erroneous code on the php which the ajax calls back. Handle the error appropriately in php to send a flag back which you detect to your js as a response of the ajax and act differently then if that error was not returned.

Comment: If you want to trigger the `error()` method you need to return the response with an error code. Something like: `http_response_code(422);` before echoing the json response should work.

Answer (score 1):

The `error` callback for jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method accepts three arguments which you can use to get more info about the error:

```
 Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

Please note that `error` callback will only be called if there is some error while getting response from the server e.g. server can't be reached or some server error occurred while trying to generate a response for your ajax request.

If your php file is able to send back a response, it's usually handled by `success` callback because in effect the ajax succeeded and returned a proper response.

If you still want to handle your custom error cases in `error` callback, you should also add http error codes in your ajax response headers.